# How do you interact with Google Groups?

Tags: google-groups, community

I've been using Google Groups to follow a few communities that I am interested in.  I've just been looking at it directly on the google groups web site.

However, I really find the site to be clumsy to use and it's hard to follow threads sometimes (I'm using abridged emails, 1 per day).

One thing that is a hassle particularly for me is that topics say something like "4 new of 21", and even after I read that thread, it still says "4 new of 21".    Is there a way to make it stop telling you there are new posts after you've looked at them?

Is there some client application or other way to access groups that is more handy to use?

Answer (score 1):

I use the rss feed on my start page to see whats new.

Comment: +1 I've tried this out, it's a handy way to read but sadly it's not very useful when you want to reply or add to the discussion.   Not ready to give up my search yet.

Answer (score 1):

I Just check the "Email (Approximately 1 email per day)" membership option of the group I want to follow. Then I get all the messages posted to the group as email messages in my inbox.
I use gmail to read them or reply to them. Very handy as the mails stay in their own thread. No need to visit the site anymore.
You can even apply a filter and let them automatically be removed from your inbox if you don't want them there.

Comment: +1 I've tried this in gmail, it works reasonably well, but it still feels awkward and things just don't seem like a cohesive thread (although its better than the regular google groups gui).

Answer (score 0):

I use [Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/) for reading newsgroups.